# Authenticated Web App Scanning in Nessus using HTTP login form and HTTP cookies import issues

Tags: security, web-applications, nessus, application-security

Context: Run Nessus web application scan using Authentication credentials [HTTP login form (Login Form Authentication)](https://docs.tenable.com/nessus/Content/WebAuthentication.htm#Login-Form-Authentication);

Official guide does not help me with figuring out how to determine the login parameters of a web page;

I have already attempted the using `JSON key value pairs` (for example, `{"username": "%USER%","password": "%PASS%"})` and

also followed steps to resolve the issue, using information from below listed pages:

1. [Web Application Vulnerability Testing with Nessus
   presentation](https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/Web_Application_Vul_Testing_with_Nessus_2012.02.01.pdf); page number: `96`
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50199945/10053482
3. https://www.tenable.com/blog/scanning-web-applications-that-require-authentication
4. https://community.tenable.com/s/article/How-to-Configure-Web-Application-Authentication-in-Tenable-io-WAS
5. https://community.tenable.com/s/article/Credentialed-Web-App-Scanning-in-Nessus-6

But nothing helped for a web page which does not supports http URI query-string parameters based login.

---

Another issue that I am encountering is I am not able to debug why `Authentication / Credential Info (Hosts)` using [HTTP cookies import (Cookie Authentication)](https://docs.tenable.com/nessus/Content/WebAuthentication.htm#Cookie-Authentication) is `Failing`

For this I tried changing the logs settings as listed below

```bash
log_details: yes
log_whole_attack: yes
backend_log_level: debug
```

But I dont see any useful information in logs to understand why the authenticated scan is failing with  using [Cookie Authentication](https://docs.tenable.com/nessus/Content/WebAuthentication.htm#Cookie-Authentication)

Kindly advice